# React Router is not matching path and rendering <!-- react-empty: 1 -->

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I implemented React Router and now when webpack dev server loads my transpiled asset, I see a blank page with `<div id="container"><!-- react-empty: 1 --></div>`. Please see the entire tree below:

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"><!-- react-empty: 1 --></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Is react router not able to match the path in the browser with a Route, which prevents it from rendering my component? Am I not using the React Router API correctly? My project is hosted on github [here](https://github.com/robskrob/personal-web-app/tree/feature/add-routing) and here is my package json and start of my react app:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import Components from './components/';
import Containers from './containers/';
import store from './store';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

//<Route path='/write-post' components={Components.WritePost} />

//<Route exact path='/' components={Containers.Home} />
ReactDOM.render(
  (<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' components={Components.WritePost} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>), document.getElementById('container'));
```

package json:

```
{
  "name": "personal-web-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-server": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config webpack.js",
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Your Route should have `component` and not `components`

```
 <Route path='/' component={Components.WritePost} />
```